# Unhandled Rejection (Error): No valid "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options

Tags: ipfs

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): No valid "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options.
▶ 4 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
C:/mydapp1/client/src/App.js:38
  35 | await ipfs.add(this.state.buffer, (err, ipfsHash) => {
  36 | console.log(err,ipfsHash);
  37 | this.setState({ ipfsHash:ipfsHash[0].hash });
> 38 | storeMyValue.methods.set(this.state.ipfsHash).send({
  39 | from: accounts[1]
  40 | }, (error, transactionHash) => {
  41 | console.log("transaction hash is ",transactionHash);
```